# Checkbox like radio button jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a buch of `checkbox` in different containers like below:

```js
$("input:checkbox").click(function() {
  var url = "http://example.com/results?&"
  var flag = false;
  var $box = $(this);
  var $facet = $box.val();
  var $name = $box.attr("name");
  var group = "input:checkbox['" + $facet + $name + "']:checked";
  console.log(group);
  $("#pruebita").not(this).attr("checked", false);
  $(group).each(function() {
    if (!flag) {
      url = url + $(this).val() + $(this).attr('name');
      flag = true; // To trace if first query string added
    } else {
      url = url + "&" + $(this).val() + $(this).attr('name');
    }
  });
  console.log(url);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="cFilterAction fSpace topFM hidden-sm hidden-md hidden-lg">
  <li class="fTitle" id="genderTitle">
    <a class="filter facetTitle " id="gender">
gender
</a>
  </li>
  <div class="fct-bd colorWrap">
    <ul class="noShow-filter Wrap">
      <li class="cnv-level-1 mbs">
        <label class="facetbutton">
          <input id="pruebita" type="checkbox" name="women" value="gender=" data-facet="Gender">
          <span class="fct-scroll-item">women</span>
        </label>
      </li>
      <li class="cnv-level-1 mbs">
        <label class="facetbutton">
          <input id="pruebita" type="checkbox" name="men" value="gender=" data-facet="Gender">
          <span class="fct-scroll-item">men</span>
        </label>
      </li>

    </ul>
  </div>
</ul>
<ul class="cFilterAction fSpace topFM hidden-sm hidden-md hidden-lg">
  <li class="fTitle" id="occasionTitle">
    <a class="filter facetTitle " id="occasion">
ocassion
</a>
  </li>
  <div class="fct-bd colorWrap">
    <ul class="noShow-filter Wrap">
      <li class="cnv-level-1 mbs">
        <label class="facetbutton">
          <input id="pruebita" type="checkbox" name="beach" value="occasion=" data-facet="Occasion">
          <span class="fct-scroll-item">beach</span>
        </label>
      </li>
      <li class="cnv-level-1 mbs">
        <label class="facetbutton">
          <input id="pruebita" type="checkbox" name="street" value="occasion=" data-facet="Occasion">
          <span class="fct-scroll-item">street</span>
        </label>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</ul>
```

I want that the checkboxes don't uncheck the previous option when checking another section of checkboxes.

The complete code is also at [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/j1wo9hat/6/)

Comment: remove this line `$("#pruebita").not(this).attr("checked",false);`

Comment: If you want only one value selected, then use radio buttons instead of checkboxes.

Comment: @Azim I want to still checked gender when I check occasion

Answer (score 1):

In your code you have

```
$("#pruebita").not(this).attr("checked",false);
```

Which essentially is unchecking all the checkboxes except the clicked one. Removing this line of code will make it work fine.

See updated [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/j1wo9hat/11/)

Comment: Thank you @void but for example if i check gender is correct that uncheck male when i check female or viceversa but if i check some option of occasion gender is uncheck and only can check occasion and I want to mantain checked gender when I check occasion

Comment: @victor first of all in your code you have multiple elements with same ID. which is wrong. Use class instead. Can you fix this first then I can hep you debugging your code.

Comment: Thank you for the observation I'll change that and I notify you

Answer (score 0):

You don't need any javascript at all for this problem; you just need to use appropriate form elements and set their attributes correctly.

Radio buttons are for when only one of a group of options should be selectable; checkboxes are for when more than one should be selectable. They aren't interchangeable. **Do not use javascript to disguise radio button functionality as checkbox elements**; that's bad usability, as it gives the user incorrect expectations about how the form will work.

Part of the problem is that you've confused the purpose of the "name" and "value" attributes.  The "name" attribute is for defining which group the radio buttons belong to; all radio buttons with the same name will be in the same group. The "value" attribute contains the value that will be submitted as part of the form if that option is selected.  You had them backwards:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="women" value="gender=" ...>
<input type="checkbox" name="men" value="gender=" ...>
```

With the above code, all the boxes have a unique 'name', so none of them would be grouped; meanwhile the user's selection wouldn't have any effect, since they both have the same value.   Instead, that should be this:

```
<input type="radio" name="gender" value="women" ...>
<input type="radio" name="gender" value="men" ...>
```

That HTML will cause the form field "gender" to contain the value "women" or "men", depending on the user's selection. Here's the full corrected example:

```html
<ul class="cFilterAction fSpace topFM hidden-sm hidden-md hidden-lg">
  <li class="fTitle" id="genderTitle">
    <a class="filter facetTitle" id="gender">gender</a>
  </li>
  <div class="fct-bd colorWrap">
    <ul class="noShow-filter Wrap">
      <li class="cnv-level-1 mbs">
        <label class="facetbutton">
          <input id="pruebita" type="radio" name="gender" value="women" data-facet="Gender">
          <span class="fct-scroll-item">women</span>
        </label>
      </li>
      <li class="cnv-level-1 mbs">
        <label class="facetbutton">
          <input id="pruebita" type="radio" name="gender" value="men" data-facet="Gender">
          <span class="fct-scroll-item">men</span>
        </label>
      </li>

    </ul>
  </div>
</ul>
<ul class="cFilterAction fSpace topFM hidden-sm hidden-md hidden-lg">
  <li class="fTitle" id="occasionTitle">
    <a class="filter facetTitle " id="occasion">ocassion</a>
  </li>
  <div class="fct-bd colorWrap">
    <ul class="noShow-filter Wrap">
      <li class="cnv-level-1 mbs">
        <label class="facetbutton">
          <input id="pruebita" type="radio" name="occasion" value="beach" data-facet="Occasion">
          <span class="fct-scroll-item">beach</span>
        </label>
      </li>
      <li class="cnv-level-1 mbs">
        <label class="facetbutton">
          <input id="pruebita" type="radio" name="occasion" value="street" data-facet="Occasion">
          <span class="fct-scroll-item">street</span>
        </label>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</ul>
```